# PHP - Loop through all links, remove content after last occurance

Tags: php, regex, loops, hyperlink

I have a variable that contains an entire article including text and some links.

I need to loop through the content in the variable and find all instances of links containing a specific word. Once they have been found, I then need to remove everything after the last / in each of the found URL's.

For example:
Let's say the page has 8 links - 4 of them contain the word "article".
I need to find each of those links that contain the word "article" and then remove everything after the last occurrence of / in each of those links.

So far I've tried using some Regex such as:

```
    /<a.*?href\s*=\s*["\']([^"\'>]*article[^"\'>]*)["\'][^>]*>.*?<\/a>/si
```

But haven't found a way to actually replace everything after the last /

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: The articles are dynamic, so the links and content are never the same. They are retrieved from the database and stored in a single variable.. with HTML markup already included.

Comment: This is a job for DOM not regex.

Comment: Even though the content isn't on the page yet? This is content that is being retrieved from the MySQL database and needs these changes made prior to output on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM tools means that you care much more about your CPU. I don't say RegEx, that is meant to be used totally for text-processing, is not a proper tool for offering a solution but well, specific tool for specific job is always almost cleaner and does perform better.

By what you have said already, I modified your regex in this way:

```
(<a(?>.+?)href\s*=\s*(["'])(?>[^"'><]*?article)(?>[^>]*?/))(.*?)(\2.*?>[^<]++</a>)
```

and you only need to replace a complete match with 1st and 4th captured groups. So the code would be:

```
echo preg_replace('~(<a(?>.+?)href\s*=\s*(["\'])(?>[^"\'><]*?article)(?>[^>]*?/))(.*?)(\2.*?>[^<]++</a>)~s', '\1\4', $html);
```

I have made a [live demo](https://3v4l.org/OGq0e) as well.